# How to avoid writing tensorboard logs to local directory when using s3 path?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I want to write logs to s3 and tensorboard does that for me. However, it writes empty folders to local directory too. I am using pytorch lightning and tensorboard, the code is like:

```py
data = DataModule(**dict_args)
model = BaseModel(**dict_args)
tb_logger = TensorBoardLogger("s3://my-bucket/path")
trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(
        args,
        logger=tb_logger,
        max_epochs=args.epochs,
    )
trainer.fit(model, datamodule=data)
```

This snippet of code writes logs to both s3 and a local directory `s3:/my-bucket/path`. There are no files under the directory, which is good, but I wonder if I can do something to avoid writing to local directory.

Comment: Which `pytorch-lightning` version are you using?

Comment: @Berriel pytorch_lightning 1.4.1

Comment: Hmm... it shouldn't happen. Could you debug to check where in TensorBoardLogger the local dir is created? I don't have access to a s3 bucket right now. Anyway, you won't find any interface to disable it as of now. This would be worth an issue on their github if someone else can reproduce the problem.